# Braintree Paypal works in Sandbox but not production

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, braintree

I am using Paypal/Braintree with PHP sdk and setting up Vault flow to create subscriptions. It all worked fine in Sandbox but now in product I get error code 93108, message: Unknown paymentMethodNonce.

My client side code is:

```
braintree.setup(GFormVATVars.br_client_token, "paypal", {
                container: "paypal-container",
                singleUse: false,
                onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
                    $(".gform_next_button").show();
                    $("span#br_pp_message").html('<img height="15" width="15" src="'+GFormVATVars.spinner_gif+'"/>');
                     $.post(GFormVATVars.ajaxurl,{action: 'process_br_pp_payment_token',token: obj.nonce,security: GFormVATVars.security},function(response) {
                        $("span#br_pp_message").html(response);
                    });
                    return;
                }
            });
```

In the Ajax request I save the nonce, and then use it in the Braintree_Customer::create

My server side code is:

```
$cargs = array(
                'firstName' => $entry["6.3"],
                'lastName' => $entry["6.6"],
                'company' => $entry["18"],
                'email' => $entry["7"]
$cargs['paymentMethodNonce'] = $_SESSION['wswp_payment_token'];

                                file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/logbeforectry.php",print_r($cargs,true));
                                try {

                    // Configure Braintree environment
                    Braintree_Configuration::environment( strtolower( $settings['environment'] ) );
                    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId( $settings['merchant-id']);
                    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey( $settings['public-key'] );
                    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey( $settings['private-key'] );
                                    $cresult = Braintree_Customer::create($cargs);
                                    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/logcresult.php",print_r($cresult,true));
                                }
                               catch( Exception $e ) {
                                file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/catchcresult.php",print_r($e->getMessage(),true));
                    // Do nothing with exception object, just fallback to generic failure
                }
```

It brings back the error response as described above. I have checked and the parameters for $cargs are all filled as they should be, including the fact that the nonce has the value of the payment_method_nonce filled after logging in via the popup. The strange thing is that if you hit the button and authorize again it works. Please help I am tearing my hair out with this one.

Comment: so as my understand (i am not good in paypal),, if you send the request twice, it will work , so did you try to save the first request and the second in some where and then see the difference

Comment: I have since reduced the arguments sent into Braintree_Customer::create to just have paymentMethodNonce for Paypal payments, and it still fails first time and succeeds second. Comparing the request shows the nonce going through successfully both times.

Comment: you need to compare the parameters which are sent to paypal in first time and second time ... i know it must be same .. but just we should do this ... because if same params and same request ,, it must give same results

Comment: hi Liam.  I'm a developer on the Pay with PayPal team at Braintree.  To clarify, you have viewed the output in logbeforectry for each request, and the each of those requests contains a payment method nonce?

Comment: If this is the case, and you still cannot get the first request to go through I'd encourage you to reach out to our support team at support@braintreepayments.com.  Feel free to link this question and include my name (Goggin), and we will take a look at the logs on our side to verify that the payment method nonce parameter is being sent through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close this issue out, the Braintree support team helped diagnose the issue, which was that the client token being generated was from the Braintree Sandbox environment and then used in the Braintree production environment.